# MySQL "Close All Like This"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I open several tabs to browse tables in my database, I can then right-click on a tab and have a few options to close them:

1. Close
2. Close All
3. Close All Like This
4. Close All But This

1) 2) and 4) are pretty obvious to me, but I have no idea what option 3) does.

Comment: some tabs are having queries and some are having procedures ,some having functions those are the diffrent things which are alike .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 main types of tabs you can open in MySQL Workbench:

```
1. SQL IDE tabs
2. Model Overview tabs
3. Model Diagram tabs
```

Additionally, there are some supplementary pages like the output page, migration and schema transfer.

ATM you can only have a single overview tab open (only one model loaded) and there can always be only one home screen and one output page, but for the others it is sometimes useful to close any of the same type (e.g. several query tabs to the same server) except the current one. This is where "Close All Like This" comes into play.

"Close All But This" is similar as it keeps the current page open, but might have unwanted side effects. For instance when you trigger that for a diagram page then all other pages, including the model page that actually owns the diagram page are closed, closing so effectively also the diagram page you wanted to keep open.